# Node.js and Cloud Functions for Firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I installed node.js on mac and window. I run the installation for functions : `npm install -g firebase-tools`. At the end of the installation after I type `firebase init`. I should get word's in black and yellow but I didn't get that. Also in both system I just got 90 packages installed. When I deploy after editing the index.js and run it with `firebase deploy`, it shows like 6 lines of functions and said , . I waited for packages to install but after a minute said deploy complete and don't show the successful deployment. Nothing show in the console.

Comment: When to install firebase tools have error ?

Comment: Please show everything that `firebase init` printed.  As your description stands now, there is nothing to help us see what went wrong.